# HighCharts : Polar chart not stretched in its frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to display a small polar chart on my web site.

But there is an anoying behaviour. the container (circle) of the chart do not fit with the chart, it grow step by step. If a value is just too big, the chart will be lost in a huge empty circle.

Please, have a look on this jsfiddle to understand the problem :
http://jsfiddle.net/7zmT9/

Is it possible to force the frame to fit the chart? or to reduce the step value?

Here is my code :

```
$(function () {

$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        polar: true,
         height: 252,
         width: 262
    },
    pane:{
      size: '100%',
  },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Polar Chart'
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 360
    },

    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 45,
        min: 0,
        max: 360,
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value + '°';
            }
        }
    },

    yAxis: {
        min: 0
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: 0,
            pointInterval: 45
        },
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0
        }
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Column',
        data: [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 20], // replace 20 by 18 to see the a more fitted chart
        pointPlacement: 'between'
    }, {
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Line',
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    }, {
        type: 'area',
        name: 'Area',
        data: [1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5]
    }]
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Universal solution is to set `maxPadding: 0` and **sometimes** `endOnTick: false`. See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7zmT9/4/

```
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        maxPadding: 0
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed set the step, but I am not 100% sure if this is what you are looking for.

On your yAxis you can set the `tickInterval`

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    tickInterval: 2 //change this value to suit your needs
},
```

I have updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zmT9/1/). Is that what you are after?

Comment: thanks, set the step solve the problem, but it create a new issue : the huge number of cyclic axis...